# How to declare a variable as a global variable once? [Python]

Tags: python, global-variables

How do I declare a variable as a global variable in python? So what I'm trying to do is make an arcade game where a variable called "money" is global, and each time you visit a game, the money goes down by five. Code:

money = 0

global money

Basically I want to declare money as "0" once, then make that a global variable.

Comment: If you declare `money` outside of any function, it will be global. To bring it inside the scope of a function, at the top you should write `global money`.

BTW, the cleanest way to carry around this scope would be to create a `class Arcade` which contains this money variable and all games can access it within. This way, there are no global variables which can be somewhat tricky in python as variables don't need to be declared.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: @quamrana Whats so bad about using globals, anyways? I don't understand.

Comment: They are very difficult to reason about and are easy to abuse.

Comment: And they make the internals of one function, that uses the global dependent, on the internals of another, that sets it. Which defeats a major goal  of having functions, which is to modularize the code and not have such dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This [w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) should be what you're looking for.

#### TL;DR

My understanding is that any variable defined outside of a function is technically global.  To make a global variable accessible within a function you must use the global keyword.  The global keyword is both able to create global variables and make them accessible within a function.  My own experimentation is shown below:

```
>>> money = 0
>>> def changeMoney(newMoney):
...     money += newMoney
... 
>>> print(str(money))
0
>>> changeMoney(7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in changeMoney
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before assignment
>>> def changeMoney(newMoney):
...     global money
...     money += newMoney
... 
>>> print(str(money))
0
>>> changeMoney(7)
>>> print(str(money))
7
>>> changeMoney(7)
>>> print(str(money))
14
>>> money += 1
>>> print(str(money))
15
>>> changeMoney(7)
>>> print(str(money))
22
```

Rereading your message, if you don't want to deal with global statements you may want to look into Python classes (not a coding course, but a thing in Python) and using instance variables.